# Vue3 SEO, trying to set Title using VueUse, but Title is still not there in source view

Tags: vuejs3, vueuse

My code:

```
import { useTitle } from '@vueuse/core'

const title = useTitle()
title.value = "Title Test"
useTitle(title)
```

I can see the title changed only on page, but if I look into the view source, title is not there.

[image]
[image]

That means, the title is ONLY available to users, users can "see" it, but not Search Enginee, right? How can i make it available to Search Enginee?

Any comments are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: First View Source only shows you the source when the page was first rendered. Anything changed with Vue, or even plain JS wont be seen there. Only if you inspect an element and search the header from there you can see it. But either way, SEOs only see what is there when the page loads, so this approach wont work either way. You'd need to use SSR if you want it to be rendered by Vue.